# What event do i use to trigger something like a mousedown in XAML (XamarinForms)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to be able to fire an event when the user is doing like a mousedown on
a grid. (Like a visual feedback that the user is tapping the grid but not a click!)

I have this XAML code:

```
 <Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger Event="MouseDown">
        <local:MouseOver/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

And this in a c# class:

```
 public class MouseOver : TriggerAction<Entry>
{
    protected async override void Invoke(Entry entry)
    {
        //Some animation code here
    }
}
```

Well i am never able to get in the event, even though the class is implemented correctly! I also tried `"IsMouseOver"` and `"MouseEnter"` as Events but none of that seems to work.
I hope someone here can help me...
Thx for your help!

Comment: Hi @Cambaru, did you able to figure it out. I am also in the same situation, I need to implement mouse events for WPF using xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 1):

`EventTrigger` only works for events that are present on the `Grid` class (or one of it's super classes). In XForms there aren't any mouse events as it's mostly designed for touch interfaces.

To add tap handling to a control i XForms is done by adding a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `GestureRecognizers` collection on the control.

```
// In C#
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
};
image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

// In XAML
<Grid Source="tapped.jpg">
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
  </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>
```

You can read up on in the [XForms docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/).

Comment: But isnt "tapped" the same as clicked?

Comment: In XForms, yes.

Comment: And there is now way to get an event when the user only put his finger on and doesnt leave?

Comment: Hold gestures aren't support out of the box. I know [MrGestures](http://www.mrgestures.com/) is a popular solution. If not you'll have to create a custom renderer and implement a hold listener.